# ActionFunction won't call controller function without Alert Message

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I'm trying to capture the selected tab in my controller.  I have the below code and it works fine if I leave in the alert message in the script.  Once I remove the alert it no longer seems to make the call to the controller.  I'm only displaying one tab in the code snippet.  I have 3 others defined.

```
<apex:page showheader="true" sidebar="true" controller="mycontroller">
<script>
    function setActiveTabJava(value){
        alert('here');
        setActiveTab(value);
    }
</script>
<apex:form >
  <apex:actionFunction id="activeTab" name="setActiveTab" action="{!setTab}" reRender="">
     <apex:param name="activeTab" assignTo="{!activeTab}" value=""/>
  </apex:actionFunction>
</apex:form>
<apex:pageblock >
    <apex:tabpanel selectedtab="Tab One" width="100%">
        <apex:tab label="This is tab one" name="tabone" id="referralTab" ontabenter="setActTabJava('TAB1');">
            <!-- other tab code-->          
        </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabpanel>
</apex:pageblock>
```

Comment: post your controller code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I basically fixed this by using the value attribute on the tab panel.  Since my controller only interested in know which tab was selected, and not when the tab was selected it worked.  Basically:

```
<apex:tabpanel value="{!activeTab}">
  <apex:tab name="tab1">...</apex:Tab>
```

So whenever a tab is changed, as long as you've specified a name attribute on the tab it will be accessible in your controller.

So sorry I no longer have that controller code to post but it was basically just a method that set a variable in the controller.